# who splits the file in hadoop? Is it Job Tracker?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to know 
when client stores data into hdfs, who exactly performs the task of splitting the Large file into smaller chunks?
Does the client directly write the data into DataNodes? If it is so, when does the data got splitted in to 64 MB or 128 MB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JobClient does that not the job tracker

> Job Client computes input splits on the data located in the input path
>   on the HDFS specified while running the job. the article says then Job
>   Client copies the resources(jars and computed input splits) to the HDFS.

The input itself relies on the cluster. The client only computes on the meta information it got from the namenode (block size, data length, block locations). These `computed` input splits carry meta information to the tasks, e.G. of the block offset and the length to compute on.